# Trying to insert datagridview into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to import my datagridview data into my SQL Server database, But I am getting an error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a DataGridView TextVoxCell to a variabletype

Can someone please guide me on a right path?

```
for (int r = 1; r < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT into RosterTest (EmployeeID, Date, ShiftType) Values (@EmployeeID,@Date,@ShiftType", con);

            query.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderText;
            query.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0];
            query.Parameters.Add("ShiftType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c];

            con.Open();
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to get the value of the cells, not the `Cell` object itself. The only reason that compiles is that the value of a parameter is just `object`, so it will accept anything you give it, even if it is not a valid parameter value.

Comment: Cant pass the Cells object to the database? Try Cells[c].value. And probably do some type checking first.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Value to your cell, it's the property containing the information.

```
query.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Added .Value to my query Parameters. Inserting now works!

```
for (int r = 0; r < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 1; c < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; c++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT into RosterTest (EmployeeID, Date, ShiftID) Values (@EmployeeID,@Date,@ShiftID)", con);
                        query.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderText;
                        query.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value;
                        query.Parameters.Add("@ShiftID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                        con.Open();
                        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
```